# LaTeX3 Verbatim-Like Command Illegal in Argument

Tags: xstring, tabularray

*LaTeX cmd: Verbatim-like command '\checkboxYesNo' illegal in argument.*

I get the above message when I tried to migrate away from using `tabu` & `xstring` combination to `tabularray` & native `LaTeX3` combination for creating a requirements table. I use `\checkboxYesNo` to determine if the state of some checkboxes that are embedded into the table. This macro is embedded in a larger one, as it gets called 4 times per call to the larger one. I have attached a MWE with comments on what to comment out to make it work correctly. If I switch in the old `\checkboxYesNoOld` function, it will work with the new `tabularray` package.

I am not sure how to embed a macro inside a second one where inner macro makes decision based on the inputs being fed to it. I read through some of the other previous answers but I just cannot wrap my head around this issue.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabu}  
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularray} % Replaces 'tabu', 'tabularx', & 'multirow'
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs} % Used by 'tabularray' to load packages for internal use
\usepackage{xstring} % Needed for "checkboxYesNoOld" command

\newcommand{\checkYes}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, line width=1.0pt]%
  \draw 
    (     0,      0) -- + 
    (     0,  1.5ex) -- + 
    ( 1.5ex,  1.5ex) -- + 
    ( 1.5ex,      0) -- 
    cycle

    ( 0.3ex,  0.3ex) -- +
    ( 0.9ex,  0.9ex)

    ( 0.3ex,  1.2ex) -- + 
    ( 0.9ex, -0.9ex);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

% Creates Unchecked Checkbox
\newcommand{\checkNo}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, line width=1.0pt]%
  \draw 
    (     0,      0) -- + 
    (     0,  1.5ex) -- + 
    ( 1.5ex,  1.5ex) -- + 
    ( 1.5ex,      0) -- 
    cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\checkboxYesNo}{vv}
{
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \str_if_in:nn {ee} { TF, T, F }
  \str_if_in:eeTF { \str_foldcase:n { #2 } } { \str_foldcase:n { #1 } } {\checkYes} {\checkNo}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\checkboxYesNoOld}[2]{
  %% #1--Find This;  #2--Search This List
  %% Outputs a Checked or Unchecked box 
  \lowercase{\def\myList{#2}}%
  \lowercase{\def\findMe{#1}}%
  \IfSubStr{\myList}{\findMe}{\checkYes}{\checkNo}%
  % \IfSubStr{\myList}{\findMe}{Yes \findMe - \myList}{No \findMe - \myList}%
}

\newcommand{\reqUserOld}[6]{% 
  \begin{tabu} to 0.99\textwidth{p{60pt}  *{3}{p{1pt} X[2,l] } p{1pt} X[3,l] }
    \toprule
    {\small \textbf{Req Name}} & \multicolumn{8}{l}{\textbf{#2}} \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(l){2-9}
    {\small Req ID} & \multicolumn{8}{l}{#1} \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(l){2-9}
    {\small Requirement} & \multicolumn{8}{l}{#3} \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(l){2-9}
    {\small Remarks} & \multicolumn{8}{l}{#4} \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(l){2-9}
    {\small Parent} & \multicolumn{8}{l}{#5} \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(l){2-9}
    {\small Verification} & 

%%%% Use this for "correct" output
    %{\small \checkYes} & {\small Test} & 
    %{\small \checkNo}  & {\small Analysis} & 
    %{\small \checkNo}  & {\small Inspection} &
    %{\small \checkYes} & {\small Review-of-Design} \\
    
%%%% This may cause a different error.
    {\small \checkboxYesNoOld{t}{#6}} & {\small Test} & 
    {\small \checkboxYesNoOld{a}{#6}} & {\small Analysis} & 
    {\small \checkboxYesNoOld{i}{#6}} & {\small Inspection} & 
    {\small \checkboxYesNoOld{r}{#6}} & {\small Review-of-Design} \\

    \bottomrule
    \tabuphantomline
  \end{tabu}
}

\newcommand{\reqUser}[6]{% 
  \begin{tblr}{
    width    =  0.99\textwidth, 
    colspec  =  {t{60pt}  *{3}{t{1pt} X[2,l] } t{1pt} X[3,l]}
    }

    \toprule
    {\small \textbf{Req Name}} & \SetCell[r=1,c=8]{l}{\textbf{#2}} \\

    \cmidrule[r]{1-1} \cmidrule[l]{2-9}
    {\small Req ID}       & \SetCell[r=1,c=8]{l}{#1} \\
    \cmidrule[r]{1-1} \cmidrule[l]{2-9}
    {\small Requirement}  & \SetCell[r=1,c=8]{l}{#3} \\
    \cmidrule[r]{1-1} \cmidrule[l]{2-9}
    {\small Remarks}      & \SetCell[r=1,c=8]{l}{#4} \\
    \cmidrule[r]{1-1} \cmidrule[l]{2-9}
    {\small Parent}       & \SetCell[r=1,c=8]{l}{#5} \\
    \cmidrule[r]{1-1} \cmidrule[l]{2-9}

    {\small Verification} &  
    {\small \checkboxYesNoOld{t}{#6}} & {\small Test} & 
    {\small \checkboxYesNoOld{a}{#6}} & {\small Analysis} & 
    {\small \checkboxYesNoOld{i}{#6}} & {\small Inspection} & 
    {\small \checkboxYesNoOld{r}{#6}} & {\small Review-of-Design}  
    \bottomrule
  \end{tblr}  % ! So the `\checkboxYesNo` command is causing the table to be super tall
}


\begin{document}

% This produces the desired results under the old `tabu`/`xstring` system
\reqUserOld{M-03}{Req Name 3}{A description}{Some remarks}{The Parent Requirement}{tr}

%% Use this for "error" output (The verbatim command '\checkboxYesNo' cannot be used inside)
%\reqUser{M-03}{Req Name 3}{A description}{Some remarks}{The Parent Requirement}{tr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can't grab verbatim material inside arguments: it's not clear why you are trying that with the `expl3` solution but using classical argument handling with your older one

Comment: Well, catcode is a complex topic in TeX. For simplicity, just assume you can't (it's too simple and *limiting* though. If you want to try to learn serious TeX programming try [package writing - Where do I start LaTeX programming? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/where-do-i-start-latex-programming/))

Comment: Actually... in this case it appears you just need to define the **largest** one to grab argument verbatim, then pass it to normal inner ones. Nevertheless you never show where you want to try using the argument so we can't tell (there's no example of argument that requires verbatim in your document)

Comment: You should move your `\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn` outside of your macro definition. This doesn't need to run everytime you call your macro, just use it once in your preamble. And like other's already said, instead of `v v` as argument specifier in your `\NewDocumentCommand`, use `m m` instead and everything should work as you expect.

Comment: And if every cell in your table should be `\small`, it might be a good idea to use `\small` outside the table instead of in every cell (and if a single cell shouldn't be small you could use `\normalsize` there).

Comment: Also, in your `tikzpicture`s you could use `\draw (0,0) rectangle (1.5ex, 1.5ex);` instead of your `cycle`-construct to draw the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following does include a few corrections:

- using `mm` instead of `vv` as arguments
- only generate the variants of `\str_if_in:nnTF` once
- using `rectangle` in your `tikzpicture`
- move the box drawing to another macro (reduced code duplication for your `\checkYes`/`\checkNo`)
- specify `\small` for the entire first column
- use only two columns instead of 9 and joining the last 8 in every but the last row
- there was a `\\` missing before the `\bottomrule`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabu}  
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularray} % Replaces 'tabu', 'tabularx', & 'multirow'
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs} % Used by 'tabularray' to load packages for internal use
\usepackage{xstring} % Needed for "checkboxYesNoOld" command

\newcommand\checkboxBox[1]
  {%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, line width=1.0pt]
      \draw (0,0) rectangle (1.5ex, 1.5ex) #1;
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
\newcommand{\checkYes}{%
  \checkboxBox
    {%
      ( 0.3ex,  0.3ex) -- +
      ( 0.9ex,  0.9ex)
      ( 0.3ex,  1.2ex) -- + 
      ( 0.9ex, -0.9ex)
    }%
}

% Creates Unchecked Checkbox
\newcommand{\checkNo}{\checkboxBox{}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \str_if_in:nn {ee} { TF, T, F }
\NewDocumentCommand{\checkboxYesNo}{mm}
  {
    \str_if_in:eeTF { \str_foldcase:n { #2 } } { \str_foldcase:n { #1 } }
      {\checkYes}
      {\checkNo}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\checkboxYesNoOld}[2]{
  %% #1--Find This;  #2--Search This List
  %% Outputs a Checked or Unchecked box 
  \lowercase{\def\myList{#2}}%
  \lowercase{\def\findMe{#1}}%
  \IfSubStr{\myList}{\findMe}{\checkYes}{\checkNo}%
  % \IfSubStr{\myList}{\findMe}{Yes \findMe - \myList}{No \findMe - \myList}%
}

\newcommand{\reqUserOld}[6]{% 
  \begingroup
  \small
  \begin{tabu} to 0.99\textwidth{p{60pt}  *{3}{p{1pt} X[2,l] } p{1pt} X[3,l] }
    \toprule
    {\small \textbf{Req Name}} & \multicolumn{8}{l}{\textbf{#2}} \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(l){2-9}
    {\small Req ID} & \multicolumn{8}{l}{#1} \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(l){2-9}
    {\small Requirement} & \multicolumn{8}{l}{#3} \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(l){2-9}
    {\small Remarks} & \multicolumn{8}{l}{#4} \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(l){2-9}
    {\small Parent} & \multicolumn{8}{l}{#5} \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(l){2-9}
    {\small Verification} & 

%%%% Use this for "correct" output
    %{\small \checkYes} & {\small Test} & 
    %{\small \checkNo}  & {\small Analysis} & 
    %{\small \checkNo}  & {\small Inspection} &
    %{\small \checkYes} & {\small Review-of-Design} \\
    
%%%% This may cause a different error.
    {\small \checkboxYesNoOld{t}{#6}} & {\small Test} & 
    {\small \checkboxYesNoOld{a}{#6}} & {\small Analysis} & 
    {\small \checkboxYesNoOld{i}{#6}} & {\small Inspection} & 
    {\small \checkboxYesNoOld{r}{#6}} & {\small Review-of-Design} \\

    \bottomrule
    \tabuphantomline
  \end{tabu}
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand{\reqUser}[6]{% 
  \begin{tblr}{
    width    =  0.99\textwidth,
    colspec  =  {>{\small}h{60pt}  X}
    }

    \toprule
    \textbf{Req Name} & \textbf{#2} \\

    \cmidrule[r]{1-1} \cmidrule[l]{2-2}
    Req ID       & #1 \\
    \cmidrule[r]{1-1} \cmidrule[l]{2-2}
    Requirement  & #3 \\
    \cmidrule[r]{1-1} \cmidrule[l]{2-2}
    Remarks      & #4 \\
    \cmidrule[r]{1-1} \cmidrule[l]{2-2}
    Parent       & #5 \\
    \cmidrule[r]{1-1} \cmidrule[l]{2-2}

    Verification &
      \small
      \checkboxYesNoOld{t}{#6} Test \hfill
      \checkboxYesNoOld{a}{#6} Analysis \hfill
      \checkboxYesNoOld{i}{#6} Inspection \hfill
      \checkboxYesNoOld{r}{#6} Review-of-Design \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tblr}  % ! So the `\checkboxYesNo` command is causing the table to be super tall
}


\begin{document}

% This produces the desired results under the old `tabu`/`xstring` system
\noindent
\reqUserOld{M-03}{Req Name 3}{A description}{Some remarks}{The Parent Requirement}{tr}

%% Use this for "error" output (The verbatim command '\checkboxYesNo' cannot be used inside)
\noindent
\reqUser{M-03}{Req Name 3}{A description}{Some remarks}{The Parent Requirement}{tr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Asides from answering all my questions, you managed to answer a question about `\hfill` I didn't know I had.